# windows 10 start menu pinned onto one of my screens?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I know it is uncommon but I liked the windows 8 start screen, as I display it on a second screen to have my apps updated with dynamic tiles.
I would like to know if it would be possible to have the same layout with windows 10, i.e. with the start menu pinned onto one of my screens permanently.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can defiantly do that. Go to settings, click on Personalization, then select the Start from the list and finally turn on Use Start Full Screen. Feel free to click on links below to check out screen shots.

[Screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGi1r.jpg)

[Screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogLI6.jpg)

[Screen shot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZwZx.jpg)

Comment: Yes I know that but how can I pin it (have it permanently open in one of my screen)?

Comment: As far as I know you can't. But why do you need it to be open in a separate window?